# Calculating daily average count of each category in Spotfire when some categories do not appear on every day

Tags: filtering, average, spotfire, tibco

I have a data table in Spotfire which has a list of items belonging to different management groups. Each management group gets new items every day. I want to calculate the daily average number of items for each management group over a filtered range of dates. Not every management group gets new items every day.

I created a pie chart that is colored by [management group].

After I filtered the range of dates to **9/25/2023 - 9/27/2023**, I tried to size each sector with the expression:

> count([item]) / uniqueCount([date])

I expected this to divide the total number of items in each management group by the number of dates in my range, **3**.

This worked for most of the management groups, which have items for each day, but one management group, "K", only has **1** item for **9/27/2023**, and no other items on the other dates, so the uniqueCount of dates for that management group is 1, thus the displayed average for management group "K" is 1.

[Incorrect Pie Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccRH1.png)

Management Group "K" is in yellow

I want the pie chart to show an average value of **0.33** for management group "K" (one item in three days between **9/25/2023 - 9/27/2023)**.

I can't just divide the data by 3 because it must depend on the filtered dates, so the pie chart would show a value of **0.25** when the dates are filtered to **9/24/2023 - 9/27/2023** (one item in four days), or **0.5** when filtered to **9/26/2023 - 9/27/2023** (one item in two days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try substituting the denominator with the maximum count of dates in the dataset? Something like

```
count([item]) / Max(uniqueCount([date]))
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This will suffice for now. My only concern is that the other management groups may not have items for every date going forward. So the max unique count won't necessarily reflect the total number of days.

Comment: another solution would be to join a dataset with all the required dates to this. It would make the total number of rows larger and you would have null values in the other columns that you need to decide how to fill. Probably you would need a set of dates for each management group (otherwise assigning the right management group would be a problem)